# Duplicated Title Tag Problem in Webmaster Tools

Tags: seo, duplicate-content

I built my website four months ago and was using WordPress. I have my url set up as www.xxx.com/date/title of the post at first hand. After about three months, I change the url to be only www.xxx.com/title of the post.

And I get the the duplicated title tags in Google webmaster tools. I just know that it is the worst idea ever to change the post urls after seeing no more traffic from Google.

Please suggest me the best way to solve this problem.

Here is the screenshot of some duplicated urls. I have hundred of them.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You've actually created duplicate content. Every url is seen as a different page, and you have 2 versions of the same content. Just stick with one url and do a 301 redirect from the different version. If there's a reason to keep two versions, you can consider using a [canonical tag](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139394?hl=en).

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the anomalous behavior is change in URL scheme.

To address the issue, you can use option in Google Webmaster to demote the links with previous format.

Another option is to can Canonical URLs with new format of URLs and have 301 redirect from previous Urls to new Urls.